# como usar fetch en react para resivir datos a una base de datos mongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, url, fetch

no sé porqué, cuando uso fetch y pongo la url de la base de datos de mongoDB, me sale que mongodb+svg no es soportado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) se utiliza para peticiones o solicitudes de tipo `http`. Un servidor de MongoDB no implementa protocolo `http` para conexiones, es por ello que no puedes usar `fetch` para comunicar directamente con MongoDB. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La petición fetch desde React (frontend - cliente) tiene que ir a un servidor (backend) ya sea en nodejs en el cual hayas configurado controladores y servicios que se encargaran de tomar tu petición desde el frontend y devolverte algo, en este caso los datos que quieras de la base de datos, este último sería el servicio de la aplicación de nodejs el que se encargaría de tomar los datos de mongoDB y dárselos al controlador para que este te lo devolviese en una respuesta y puedas consumirla a través de una API.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero como debería de haberlo?